# El if solo me reconoce el ultimo elemento introducido del array

Tags: c

Cuando ingreso dos alumnos (o más) a la hora de querer mostrar si aprobó o no solo me muestra el ultimo elemento del array y los primeros que ingrese no.

Ejemplo: ingresé el primer alumno con sus tres notas luego ingreso otro pero a la hora de mostrar si los dos  alumnos aprobaron solo me muestra el ultimo agregado, el `if` solo me guarda e imprime el ultimo ingresado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int notas[3],may=0,i,opc;
    char opcion[3];
    float prom=0, suma;
    char nombre[3][20],materia[3][20];
            
    fflush(stdin);
            
    do {            
        printf("Bienvenido al sistema de notas\t\n");
        printf("\n1.Ingresar Datos y notas del estudiante\n");
        printf("\n2.Mostrar promedio y Resulatdo del curso\n");
        printf("\n3.Salir\n");
        printf("\nElija una opcion (1-3)\n");
        scanf("%d",&opc);
                
        switch (opc){
            case 1:
                do {
                    printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno\n");
                    scanf("%s",nombre);
                    printf("Ingrese la materia del estudiante\n");
                    scanf("%s",materia);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    suma=0;

                    for(i=0; i<3; i++){                         
                        printf("Ingrese la nota del estudiante\n");
                        printf("notas %d:", i+1);
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d",&notas[i]);
                        
                        suma+=notas[i];                         
                    }
                    
                    prom=suma/3;
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("El promedio de %s es: %.1f\n\n",nombre,prom);
                    printf("Desea calcular otras notas? ¿(si/no)?\n\n");
                    scanf("%s", opcion);
                } while(opcion[0]=='S' || opcion[0]=='s');
                
                break;
            case 2:
                if(prom<70){
                    printf("------El estudiante %s Reprobo -----\n\n",nombre);
                }
                else {
                    printf("------El estudiante %s Aprobo --------\n\n",nombre);
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("Usted ha salido del programa");
                break;
        }
                
    } while(opc!=3);
            
    return 0;
}
```

Este es el código en la condicional solo me muestra el ultimo elemento del array que se guardo pero necesito que se muestren los demás**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! "solo me muestra el ultimo agregado", si, eso es lo que esta escrito en tu codigo. En que parte esta eso? te das cuenta? entonces, si quisieras el promedio del primer alumno, que deberias hacer?

Comment: Agrega algunas funciones a ese código. Así se hace más fácil de leer.

Comment: Las variables `nombre` y `prom` se sobreescriben cada vez y es por eso que solo te muestra el último valor...

Comment: Gbianchi cierto bro siento que no fui lo suficiente claro, no es el promedio. es la parte de las condiciones que solo guarda los últimos datos introducidos

Comment: de que condiciones hablas??? mira el comentario de Francisco...

Comment: Tranquilo bro, no lo había notado el comentario en ese caso tendría que hacer?

Comment: Me parece raro que `char nombre[3][20]; scanf("%s",nombre);` no te dé errores.